# Parse Error when using showforms() command with Twill

Tags: python, browser, web, navigation, twill

My idea for this program is to have a simple (supposedly) script that monitors what time it is, and when it's in a certain time range (for example 6am to 7pm) it navigates to opendns.com and blocks certain websites using the web content filtering feature.

I thought I'd start it simple and just figure out the commands to login to the website and block a website and worry about the monitoring of the time etc later on. But sadly I'm having trouble with that aswell.

I'm using http://twill.idyll.org/ but not sure if that's a good idea or not. It's the only one I could find apart from mechanize (Which I couldn't find the right documentation for, but perhaps I'm just not looking in the right places)

Here is my code (well, it's not really code yet. Just a list of commands for the Python Shell):

```
from twill import get_browser
from twill.commands import *

username = "username@email.com" # email for opendns
password = "thisisthepassword" # password for opendns
b = get_browser()

b.go("https://dashboard.opendns.com/")
b.showforms()

fv("2", "username", username)
fv("2", "password", password)
showforms()

submit("sign-in")

b.showforms()

b.go ("https://dashboard.opendns.com/settings/*MYNETWORKID*/content_filtering") # I replaced my network ID due to privacy reasons but this is basically the URL to the web content filtering page on OpenDNS for a network

b.showforms()
```

Now that's where my problem starts.
On that last b.showforms() I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#43>", line 1, in <module>
    b.showforms()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twill-0.9-py2.7.egg\twill\browser.py", line 225, in showforms
    forms = self.get_all_forms()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twill-0.9-py2.7.egg\twill\browser.py", line 259, in get_all_forms
    global_form = self._browser.global_form()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twill-0.9-py2.7.egg\twill\other_packages\_mechanize_dist\_mechanize.py", line 446, in global_form
    return self._factory.global_form
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twill-0.9-py2.7.egg\twill\utils.py", line 334, in get_global_form
    return self.factory.global_form
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twill-0.9-py2.7.egg\twill\other_packages\_mechanize_dist\_html.py", line 521, in __getattr__
    self.forms()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twill-0.9-py2.7.egg\twill\other_packages\_mechanize_dist\_html.py", line 534, in forms
    self._forms_factory.forms())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twill-0.9-py2.7.egg\twill\other_packages\_mechanize_dist\_html.py", line 226, in forms
    raise ParseError(exc)
ParseError: <unprintable ParseError object>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the twill stuff for python is not the best documentation in the world. I think you can basically forget about the "get_browser" stuff. The twill stuff is a little clearer for me this way:

```
import twill.commands as twill

username = "username@email.com" # email for opendns
password = "thisisthepassword" # password for opendns

twill.go("https://dashboard.opendns.com/")
twill.showforms()

twill.fv("2", "username", username)
twill.fv("2", "password", password)
twill.showforms()

twill.submit("sign-in")

twill.showforms()

twill.go ("https://dashboard.opendns.com/settings/*MYNETWORKID*/content_filtering") # I replaced my network ID due to privacy reasons but this is basically the URL to the web content filtering page on OpenDNS for a network

twill.showforms()
```